# How to create a document based on a local template?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

Just installed Office 2013 and I am completely lost.

How does one create a document based on a local template?  Searching for the name of the template in the top search textbox only seems to bring templates from the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `File / New / Personal` and your templates should show up:

[image: 1]

If that option is missing, go to `File/ Options / Save / Save workbooks` and enter the path to your personal templates folder in the `Default personal templates location` box:

[image]

Now any templates in that folder should show up under `File / New / Personal`.

Comment: I do not have the `Personal` or `Featured` section. http://imgur.com/2yrOj

Comment: Nowhere, not even at the bottom of all the templates if you scroll down?

Comment: Nope, nothing.  I looked up and down.  At the bottom of the list it says `Not finding what you are looking for?  Try searching at the top.`

Comment: See my edited answer above.

Comment: That did the trick.  I had nothing entered there.  Probably a bug in the upgrade routine.

Comment: Yeah, and in any case, how hard would it have been for MS to display the Personal link and direct the user to that option with a message if the location was blank? Also, the link itself IMO could have been titled something like "My templates" to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to use templates every now and then, open the template file normally, then file -> save as, and then start modifying your new file.
(Works fine in Excel, Word, 2007 & 2010, also)